# Catkin issue - error when I am initializing a ws

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never happen before but If I create a directory `mkdir -p catkin_ws/src` and then enter `catkin build` I have the following error:

```
emeric@emeric-desktop:~/catkin_plan_ws$ catkin build
------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:             [env] /opt/ros/kinetic
Workspace:                   /home/emeric
------------------------------------------------------
Source Space:       [exists] /home/emeric/src
Log Space:         [missing] /home/emeric/logs
Build Space:        [exists] /home/emeric/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/emeric/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/emeric/install
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       DCMAKE_BUILT_TYPE=Release
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.

NOTE: Forcing CMake to run for each package.
------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/catkin", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('catkin-tools==0.4.4', 'console_scripts', 'catkin')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py", line 267, in main
    catkin_main(sysargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py", line 262, in catkin_main
    sys.exit(args.main(args) or 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/verbs/catkin_build/cli.py", line 420, in main
    summarize_build=opts.summarize  # Can be True, False, or None
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_tools/verbs/catkin_build/build.py", line 283, in build_isolated_workspace
    workspace_packages = find_packages(context.source_space_abs, exclude_subspaces=True, warnings=[])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 86, in find_packages
    packages = find_packages_allowing_duplicates(basepath, exclude_paths=exclude_paths, exclude_subspaces=exclude_subspaces, warnings=warnings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 146, in find_packages_allowing_duplicates
    xml, filename=filename, warnings=warnings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 509, in parse_package_string
    raise InvalidPackage('The manifest must contain a single "package" root tag')
catkin_pkg.package.InvalidPackage: The manifest must contain a single "package" root tag
```

Besides the build and devel folders are created in my home directory not in the catkin one.

I guess I messed up something but I do not what and thus how to fix it.

Thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314991/catkin-issue---error-when-i-am-initializing-a-ws/) by [fabriceN](https://answers.ros.org/users/31629/fabricen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2019-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-07**:
The error message is saying there is more than one package tag in the package.xml file of one of your packages. Have you looked into this?

**Comment by [fabriceN](https://answers.ros.org/users/31629/fabricen/) on 2019-02-07**:
@PeteBlakerThe3rd  - thank you for your answer. How is it possible because the catkin ws is empty, and I want to initialize it, so there is no package.xml at all.  And I do not understand why the devel and build folders are not created under the catkin workspace...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-07**:
Cross-post of [catkin/catkin_tools#534](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/534).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output shows:

```
Source Space:       [exists] /home/emeric/src
Log Space:         [missing] /home/emeric/logs
Build Space:        [exists] /home/emeric/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/emeric/devel
```

which suggests there is a `.catkin_tools` dir in `$HOME`.

It's likely that you forgot to `cd catkin_ws` after having run `mkdir -p catkin_ws/src`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabriceN](https://answers.ros.org/users/31629/fabricen/) on 2019-02-07**:
@gvdhoorn Yes that's right, I mean There was a .catkin_tools i my home directory and this is why catkin build issued an error because in the home_dir/src I have some standard c++ files.
I removed the .catkin_tools and everything is working fine
Thank you very much for your help